# ESP8266 AutoConnect ACSelect selection index

Tags: esp8266, json

I'm trying to retrieve the current selected/saved index of my `AutoConnectSelect` Right now i'm creating a type that reads the saved json:

```
 AutoConnectSelect& bright = settingsAux["scr_brightness"].as<AutoConnectSelect>();
```

How can i get the index of the element selected in `bright` as an integer?

`bright.value` and `bright.value()` are both invalid in this context.

Any help or insight into how these types work would be appreciated.

Comment: After hunting through the source, I have come to the conclusion you should try `bright.selected` and see what that does.

Comment: Thank you! .selected works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member i was looking for is `AutoConnectSelect.selected` I just subtract the value by one to get the index, as `.selected` starts from 1.